# How to count rows in a csv file and ignore the rows not in use (using python)

Tags: python, file, csv, count, row

I have a CSV file that contains the height in feet and inches and also the weight of basketball players. However, some of the data has NULL or blank space for the feet and height.

I have to conclude how many players are obese based on their BMI, calculated from their height and weight.

I found out that there are 11 players who are obese. However, I need to find the percentage of obese players within the set of data. I am having trouble figuring out how to find the total number of players (ignoring those who have NULL or none in their row).

Here is an example of the data I have:

```html
firstname lastname position firstseason lastseason h_feet h_inches weight

Marquis   Daniels    G 2003        2009      6        6   200 
Predrag  Danilovic G 1995        1996      6        5   200
Adrian   Dantley F 1976        1990      6        5   208 
Mike   Dantoni       G 1975        1975      NULL      NULL       NULL
Henry   Darcey C 1952        1952          6        7   217 
Jimmy   Darden G 1949        1949      6        1   170 
Oliver   Darden F 1967        1969      6        6.5        235 
Yinka    Dare         C 1994        1997      7        0   265 
Jesse    Dark         G 1974        1974      6        4.5        210
```

You can see that some rows have NULL for the data.

So far this is what I have for python code:

```css
def read_csv(filename):
    """
    Reads a Comma Separated Value file,
    returns a list of rows; each row is a dictionary of columns.
    """
    with open(filename, encoding="utf_8_sig") as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        rows = list(reader)
    return rows

# Try out the function
players = read_csv("players.csv")

# Print information on the first player, to demonstrate how
# to get to the data
from pprint import pprint


def is_obese(player):
    if (player["h_inches"] and player["h_feet"] and player["weight"]) == 'NULL' or (player["h_inches"] and player["h_feet"] and player["weight"]) == None:
        pass
    else:
        total_h_inches = float(player["h_feet"]) * 12 + float(player["h_inches"])
        bmi = (float(player["weight"])/(total_h_inches**2))* 703
        return bmi >= 30
        
    
count = 0

for player in players:
    if is_obese(player):
         print ('player', player["lastname"], 'is obese')
         count = count + 1
    else:
         pass
print ("The total number of obese players:", count)
```

And it returns:

```css
player Boozer is obese
player Brand is obese
player Catlett is obese
player Davis is obese
player Hamilton is obese
player Lang is obese
player Maxiell is obese
player Miller is obese
player Smith is obese
player Traylor is obese
player White is obese
The total number of obese players: 11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a counter for total number of players as well, and only add players to the counters if there are data on them.

```
# returns True only if player has all data, otherwise returns False
def has_data(player):
    return (player["h_inches"] != 'NULL' and
            player["h_feet"]   != 'NULL' and
            player["weight"]   != 'NULL' and
            player["h_inches"] is not None and
            player["h_feet"]   is not None and
            player["weight"]   is not None)

obese_count = 0
total_count = 0

for player in players:
    if has_data(player):
        if is_obese(player):
            print ('player', player["lastname"], 'is obese')
            obese_count += 1
        total_count += 1
```

Comment: Why would `has_data(player)` return data if it is `== 'NULL' or == None`? Because python is returning the players' information for the players who **have** NULL in their rows. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Should I use `!=` instead?

Comment: I reworded the conditional statement to make it clearer. `has_data()` will return True or False, and will only return True if the player has all data. Therefore you can use this function as the condition for the `if` statement (before you check the player is obese or add to any counts). Hope that helps.

Comment: And depending on your input data you may want to also check that `player["h_inches"] != ""` (empty string) as well.

Answer (score 1):

add a `count_total`:

```
count_total = 0
def is_obese(player):
if (player["h_inches"] and player["h_feet"] and player["weight"]) == 'NULL' or (player["h_inches"] and player["h_feet"] and player["weight"]) == None:
    pass
else:
    count_total +=1  # to count number of playes without NULL values
    total_h_inches = float(player["h_feet"]) * 12 + float(player["h_inches"])
    bmi = (float(player["weight"])/(total_h_inches**2))* 703
    return bmi >= 30
```

and at last :

```
print("{} of Player obesed {}%".format("Percentage",(count/float(count_total))*100)))
```